# problem while trying to find iframe with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe

I have a few `iframe` present on the page,
inside one of `iframe` we have `div` with captcha

I need to switch to `iframe` to solve the captcha

Trying to find all iframes on the page:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//iframe')
```

but receiving the following error:

```
{InvalidSelectorException}Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//iframe" is: [object HTMLIFrameElement]. It should be an element.
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

I'm using `python 3.7` and selenium `selenium==3.141.0`

URL example:

`https://www.bloomberg.com/tosv2.html?vid=&uuid=7ea5d405-0582-11ec-9bbc-784a416f4674&url=L21hcmtldHMvc2VjdG9ycy9jb21tdW5pY2F0aW9uLXNlcnZpY2Vz`

Comment: how did you end up solving this?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//iframe')
```

this will return a list of web elements. (in your case, list of web iframes web element)

so you can do

```
lst = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(lst[0])
```

to switch to first `iframe`.

you have the index now, you can change it as per the iframe, since you have more than 1 iframe.

also I believe it is better to use, `find_element` with unique iframe identifier.

**Update 1 :**

```
list_of_iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print(len(list_of_iframe))
print(type(list_of_iframe))
for ele in list_of_iframe:
   print(ele)
```

I got this output :

```
10
<class 'list'>
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{'ontouchmove': {}, 'ontouchstart': {}}
```

Ideally it should have printed the each element, unique id (hex value) but I think due to captcha and bot preventing by the application we got almost nothing. also I could not make it to switch to iframe 5, where we have that click and hold option.

Comment: it doesn't work, due to error I mentioned

Comment: Can you share the page url or relevant HTML ?

Comment: we can construct a unique locator for each iframes, then you can simply use `find_element` not `elements`

Comment: added link in description

Comment: @Roman : See the update 1 above, I think we can not automate this process.

Comment: as you can see, in your response (update 1) it returning list of dict instead of list of web elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236391/discussion-between-roman-and-cruisepandey).

Answer (score 0):

I see there are 10 iframes on that particular page, but only one, containing the captcha is visible.
So you can select that iframe with more specific locator.
Instead of

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//iframe')
```

try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@style,'block')]")
```

Comment: same exception ```{InvalidSelectorException}Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//iframe[contains(@style,'block')]" is: [object HTMLIFrameElement]. It should be an element.```

Comment: Sure, my code returns a web element. What is the left side of this expression on your side? How are you trying to use it?

Comment: No it wouldn't work since first you need to switch, you ain't doing that

Comment: Correct. To access elements inside iframe with selenium you should switch to that iframe